# JSON schema validation with PHP

Tags: php, json, validation, jsonschema

Is there any PHP library that validates a JSON object against a JSON Schema?

Comment: Implementations for various languages (and different libraries per language) are listed here: http://json-schema.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About jsonschemaphpv, although it´s not very well maintained, we use it a lot and it works. It´s a port from the js validator. It has a full test suite that runs against the php and the http://code.google.com/p/jsonschema/.

And guess what... It passes on more tests than the js. At least at the last time I run the tests. The thing is that the project is not very well structured and looks ugly. But I ensure you it´s very stable. It also allows you to validate associative arrays as objects either.

I´ve written the tests in selenium first. After that I wrote them in phpunit. I´m not sure if the phpunit tests are there.

If you give it a try and really want to use it I can start a branch for it on github with the phpunit tests.

Bruno Reis (the person who ported the js to php)

Comment: It appears the code is hosted on SourceForge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsonschemaphpv/

Comment: There is also a [GitHub](https://github.com/jesstelford/jsonschemaphp) repo.

Comment: Just to bring this up-to-date, the SourceForge repo for jsonschemaphpv seems to be outdated; but has been forked to Github here: https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema

Answer (score 13):

I'm using Justin Rainbow's JSON Schema for PHP https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema and I'm quite happy about it.

It's a fork of http://jsonschemaphpv.sourceforge.net/

You can easily install it via Composer.

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at http://json-schema.org/implementations.html . It has some validators in php and other languages.

Answer (score 5):

On the [JSON Schema website](http://json-schema.org) there is a [list of the implementions](http://json-schema.org/implementations.html), amongst other things of validators in/for PHP:

> [jsv4-php](https://github.com/geraintluff/jsv4-php) - *supports version 4* (Public Domain / MIT)
>
> [php-json-schema](https://github.com/hasbridge/php-json-schema) (MIT)
>
> [json-schema](https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema) (Berkeley)
>
> [jvalidator](https://github.com/brainly/jvalidator) (BSD3)

Answer (score 3):

You could validate not JSON, but PHP array that could be obtained from many sources (JSON, XML, Post Data). To check if your array matches pattern you could take a look at https://github.com/ptrofimov/matchmaker