# JSON data to web service- how do define expected JSON data

Tags: php, json, web-services, rest

I am building a RESTful web service in PHP that accepts JSON as its payload
.
Now, my question is, how exactly do I describe to the user the format that the JSON request comes in? I am new to JSON and don't think I have a grasp 100%.

Will the other users system basically create a data structure (such an array) with the key value pairs that I need, encode this in JSON and send it to my web service?

Do I literally give them a copy of what the array needs to look like?
Thanks!

Comment: It's common for a REST service to **output** JSON-encoded data; you really are taking **input** as JSON-encoded (and not standard GET query parameters or POST data values?)?

Comment: What is the most common? If POST values are the standard, then I will go with that. The service will accept many product codes/quantities. How do you pass this data through a POST? something like: product_1=item1&product_1_qty=2&product_2=item2&product_2_qty=5?

Comment: For updating data, yes, POST is common and required for the RESTful methodology; see my answer for full explaination

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON schema validation with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757662/json-schema-validation-with-php) - you validate against the Json schema, see http://json-schema.org/

Comment: POST data doesn't actually have to be a query string.  It is perfectly valid to post JSON-encoded data - the format of the POST data is defined using the "Content-Type" header of the outgoing request, which defaults to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", but can be anything.

If you're storing JSON data, then accepting JSON data through POST seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adhering to the guidelines of REST, the input you get from the users of the API should either be part of the URL (for a GET request; doesn't update data, i.e. `http://example.com/api/doc/1243`), or should be a POST variable (sent in the body of the HTTP request, to the same URL).

So for documentation, all you should need to do is indicate the endpoint URL (`http://example.com/api/doc/1243`), the fact they need to use POST, and what the variables are (i.e. `title`, `body`, `author`, etc.). Then users will form the proper HTTP request however they want, and on your server end, because you're using PHP, you'll pull their variables from the `$_POST` array (i.e. `$_POST['title']`, `$_POST['body']`, etc.)

Comment: Thankyou- very good answer. So, say for a shopping cart for example, how would the products be passed in the query string (as there may be many products?). Do you just do something like "product_1=test&product_1_qty=4&product_2=test2&product_2_qty=9? etc?

Comment: For adding products to a cart, you could organize it that way. Or, have the end user call the "add to cart" method multiple times, once for each product: Endpoint `/api/cart/1243/add` with data `product_id` and `quantity` called however many times is needed.

Answer (score 1):

[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#account-info) is a good example of restful api that uses JSON as payload.

You will also get a good idea about how you can document your API as well.