# How to do authentication designing a PHP REST Web Service?

Tags: php, json, web-services, rest, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How secure is sending sensitive data over https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190771/how-secure-is-sending-sensitive-data-over-https)
>   [JSON data to web service- how do define expected JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601354/json-data-to-web-service-how-do-define-expected-json-data)

I am building a REST web service that accepts JSON as its payload.
Now, my web service is very simple. It simply accepts data from a client system and creates an order in our system ( the web service is basically a wrapper for existing functionality).

Now, I authenticate users through a username and password in the application. Do I simply ask them to provide their username/password in the JSON data that they send? Is this secure?

The service runs over HTTPS.

Comment: Ok looks like it might not be a duplicate after all, but why would you create two questions with the same name, in the space of two minutes? - I suggest you edit the question title.

Comment: Security is a process, so the security question can not be answered as it is too unspecific. It depends a lot on which level of security you need. You basically ask here if HTTPS is secure or not.

Comment: Hi. Not sure what happened there. Asked a question, then asked another one and it kept my previous question their, so forgot to update the title.

Answer (score 0):

As I also wrote in the comments above, it's not really clear what you would like to know. Perhaps because there is a lot of "it depends" potential.

Let's see what you can do:

1. You can put the authentication on the transport layer, here HTTP. That would allow you to authenticate pretty early, e.g. on the (web-)server level.
2. You can pass the credentials with the json payload and then authenticate within your application. This can be combined with 1.
3. You can create an authenticated session, and pass a session key along. API requests then need to have a session, otherwise they are not accepted. This can be combined with 2. and 3.

As long as the transport layer is secure enough for you (here TLS/SSL), do whatever pleases you. Depending which pattern you choose, you will have some more work to do.

Also often next to user-credentials there is a so called API key that is used by web services to be able to map each API request to some entity, which also can play some role in authentication. However, an API-Key is something like a username and password in one, so it is not that flexible.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think option 2 was where I was heading- simply requesting the username/password in the data that they send. You mention and API key- is this simply a key that is used (such as random numbers/letters) that the user also provides in the data? The service then does a lookup on this key to see if it is valid?