# check consistence of json file before upload for restore

Tags: php, json

I made a button for restore some data into a specific wordpress options database field. This button is sending a json file to my server, then there is a php code that updates the related options field into my wordpress database. This is working as expected, but I want to make on the php server side a check before updating the data, this check must evaluate the json structure and tells if is a correct one(at least at a basic level). How can I accomplish this kind of check? this is the json structure that I'm sending to the server. The structure is always the same, but since the json file is made from a dynamically extensible form, it can grow if I add more destinations(destinazione), dates(dataPartenza) etc

**JSON**

```json
{
   "destinazione":{
      "Corfù":{
         "dataPartenza":{
            "2021-07-16":{
               "soldout":false,
               "sistemazione":{
                  "basic":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"365.00"
                     },
                     "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"50.00"
                     }
                  },
                  "comfort":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"395.00"
                     },
                     "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"60.00"
                     }
                  },
                  "superior":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"445.00"
                     },
                     "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"60.00"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "2021-07-23":{
               "soldout":false,
               "sistemazione":{
                  "basic":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"365.00"
                     },
                     "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"50.00"
                     }
                  },
                  "comfort":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"395.00"
                     },
                     "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"60.00"
                     }
                  },
                  "superior":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"445.00"
                     },
                     "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"60.00"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "2021-07-30":{
               "soldout":false,
               "sistemazione":{
                  "basic":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"365.00"
                     },
                     "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"50.00"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "2021-08-06":{
               "soldout":false,
               "sistemazione":{
                  "basic":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"365.00"
                     },
                     "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"50.00"
                     }
                  },
                  "comfort":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"385.00"
                     },
                     "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"60.00"
                     }
                  },
                  "superior":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"445.00"
                     },
                     "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"60.00"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "2021-08-13":{
               "soldout":false,
               "sistemazione":{
                  "basic":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"365.00"
                     },
                     "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"50.00"
                     }
                  },
                  "comfort":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"385.00"
                     },
                     "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"60.00"
                     }
                  },
                  "superior":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"445.00"
                     },
                     "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"60.00"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "2021-08-20":{
               "soldout":false,
               "sistemazione":{
                  "basic":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"345.00"
                     },
                     "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"50.00"
                     }
                  },
                  "comfort":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"395.00"
                     },
                     "01|superior":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"60.00"
                     }
                  },
                  "superior":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"405.00"
                     },
                     "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"60.00"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "Zante":{
         "dataPartenza":{
            "2021-07-17":{
               "soldout":false,
               "sistemazione":{
                  "basic":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"5",
                        "prezzo":"395.00"
                     },
                     "01|bilocale":{
                        "capienza":"4",
                        "prezzo":"415.00"
                     },
                     "02|studios":{
                        "capienza":"3",
                        "prezzo":"405.00"
                     },
                     "03|studios":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"425.00"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "2021-07-24":{
               "soldout":false,
               "sistemazione":{
                  "basic":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"395.00"
                     },
                     "01|bilocale ":{
                        "capienza":"4",
                        "prezzo":"425.00"
                     },
                     "02|studio":{
                        "capienza":"3",
                        "prezzo":"415.00"
                     },
                     "03|studio":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"445.00"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "2021-07-31":{
               "soldout":false,
               "sistemazione":{
                  "basic":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"395.00"
                     },
                     "01|bilocale":{
                        "capienza":"4",
                        "prezzo":"425.00"
                     },
                     "02|studio":{
                        "capienza":"3",
                        "prezzo":"415.00"
                     },
                     "03|studio":{
                        "capienza":"3",
                        "prezzo":"445.00"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "2021-08-07":{
               "soldout":false,
               "sistemazione":{
                  "basic":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"395.00"
                     },
                     "01|bilocale":{
                        "capienza":"4",
                        "prezzo":"425.00"
                     },
                     "02|studio":{
                        "capienza":"3",
                        "prezzo":"415.00"
                     },
                     "03|studio":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"445.00"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "2021-08-14":{
               "soldout":false,
               "sistemazione":{
                  "basic":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"385.00"
                     },
                     "01|bilocale":{
                        "capienza":"4",
                        "prezzo":"425.00"
                     },
                     "02|studio":{
                        "capienza":"3",
                        "prezzo":"415.00"
                     },
                     "03|studio":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"445.00"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "Pag":{
         "dataPartenza":{
            "2021-07-18":{
               "soldout":false,
               "sistemazione":{
                  "basic":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"274.00"
                     },
                     "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"3",
                        "prezzo":"30.00"
                     },
                     "02|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"50.00"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "2021-07-25":{
               "soldout":false,
               "sistemazione":{
                  "basic":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"274.00"
                     },
                     "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"3",
                        "prezzo":"30.00"
                     },
                     "02|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"50.00"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "2021-08-01":{
               "soldout":false,
               "sistemazione":{
                  "basic":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"274.00"
                     },
                     "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"3",
                        "prezzo":"30.00"
                     },
                     "02|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"50.00"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "2021-08-08":{
               "soldout":false,
               "sistemazione":{
                  "basic":{
                     "00|quota base":{
                        "capienza":"N/S",
                        "prezzo":"274.00"
                     },
                     "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"3",
                        "prezzo":"30.00"
                     },
                     "02|supplemento monolocale":{
                        "capienza":"2",
                        "prezzo":"50.00"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**edit:**
I don't understand why I'm receving downvotes for this question, I think that the provided solution is working good and is perfect for my particular setup. I cleared a little the code and the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON schema validation with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757662/json-schema-validation-with-php)

Comment: I was looking at something different, more related to my current setup

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed in this way, basically I'm lopping through every level and check the consistency of the json structure.

**PHP:**

```php
$str = '{"destinazione":{"Corfù":{"dataPartenza":{"2021-07-16":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"555.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"50.00"}},"comfort":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"395.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"60.00"}},"superior":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"445.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"60.00"}}}},"2021-07-23":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"365.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"50.00"}},"comfort":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"395.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"60.00"}},"superior":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"445.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"60.00"}}}},"2021-07-30":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"365.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"50.00"}}}},"2021-08-06":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"365.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"50.00"}},"comfort":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"385.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"60.00"}},"superior":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"445.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"60.00"}}}},"2021-08-13":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"365.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"50.00"}},"comfort":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"385.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"60.00"}},"superior":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"445.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"60.00"}}}},"2021-08-20":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"345.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"50.00"}},"comfort":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"395.00"},"01|superior":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"60.00"}},"superior":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"405.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"60.00"}}}}}},"Zante":{"dataPartenza":{"2021-07-17":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"5","prezzo":"395.00"},"01|bilocale":{"capienza":"4","prezzo":"415.00"},"02|studios":{"capienza":"3","prezzo":"405.00"},"03|studios":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"425.00"}}}},"2021-07-24":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"395.00"},"01|bilocale ":{"capienza":"4","prezzo":"425.00"},"02|studio":{"capienza":"3","prezzo":"415.00"},"03|studio":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"445.00"}}}},"2021-07-31":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"395.00"},"01|bilocale":{"capienza":"4","prezzo":"425.00"},"02|studio":{"capienza":"3","prezzo":"415.00"},"03|studio":{"capienza":"3","prezzo":"445.00"}}}},"2021-08-07":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"395.00"},"01|bilocale":{"capienza":"4","prezzo":"425.00"},"02|studio":{"capienza":"3","prezzo":"415.00"},"03|studio":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"445.00"}}}},"2021-08-14":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"385.00"},"01|bilocale":{"capienza":"4","prezzo":"425.00"},"02|studio":{"capienza":"3","prezzo":"415.00"},"03|studio":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"445.00"}}}}}},"Pag":{"dataPartenza":{"2021-07-18":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"274.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"3","prezzo":"30.00"},"02|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"50.00"}}}},"2021-07-25":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"274.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"3","prezzo":"30.00"},"02|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"50.00"}}}},"2021-08-01":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"274.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"3","prezzo":"30.00"},"02|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"50.00"}}}},"2021-08-08":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"274.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"3","prezzo":"30.00"},"02|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"50.00"}}}}}}}}';
$arr = json_decode($str,true);
$valid;
function validateDate($date)
{
    if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$date)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
    //check destinazioni not null
    foreach ( !empty($arr['destinazione']) ? $arr['destinazione'] : ['']  as $keyDest => $valueDest ) {
        if ( !empty($keyDest) ){
            $valid = true;
        } else {
            $valid = false;
            break;
        }
        //check date is yyyy-mm-dd
        foreach ( !empty($arr['destinazione'][$keyDest]['dataPartenza']) ? $arr['destinazione'][$keyDest]['dataPartenza'] : ['']  as $keyDate => $valueDate) {
            if ( !empty($keyDate) && validateDate($keyDate) == true ){
                $valid = true;
            } else {
                $valid = false;
                break 2;
            }
            //check soldout is bool
            if ( is_bool( $arr['destinazione'][$keyDest]['dataPartenza'][$keyDate]['soldout'] ) ) {
                $valid = true;
            } else {
                $valid = false;
                break 2;
            }
            //check sistemazione not null
            foreach ( !empty($arr['destinazione'][$keyDest]['dataPartenza'][$keyDate]['sistemazione']) ? $arr['destinazione'][$keyDest]['dataPartenza'][$keyDate]['sistemazione'] : ['']  as $keySist => $valueSist) {
                if ( !empty($keySist) ){
                    $valid = true;
                } else {
                    $valid = false;
                    break 3;
                } 
                //check tipologia not null
                foreach ( !empty($arr['destinazione'][$keyDest]['dataPartenza'][$keyDate]['sistemazione'][$keySist]) ? $arr['destinazione'][$keyDest]['dataPartenza'][$keyDate]['sistemazione'][$keySist] : ['']  as $keyTip => $valueTip) {
                    if ( !empty($keyTip) ){
                        $valid = true;
                    } else {
                        $valid = false;
                        break 4;
                    }
                    //check capienza not null
                    if ( !empty($arr['destinazione'][$keyDest]['dataPartenza'][$keyDate]['sistemazione'][$keySist][$keyTip]['capienza']) ) {
                        $valid = true;
                    } else {
                        $valid = false;
                        break 4;
                    }
                    //check capienza not null
                    if ( !empty($arr['destinazione'][$keyDest]['dataPartenza'][$keyDate]['sistemazione'][$keySist][$keyTip]['prezzo']) ) {
                        $valid = true;
                    } else {
                        $valid = false;
                        break 4;
                    }                
                }
            }
        }    
    }           

$valid = $valid ? 'true' : 'false';
echo 'the json string is: '. $valid;
```